# Sequelize Add Attribute to Associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have portfolios that have many banners.

I initially used `portfolio.setBanners([1,2,3])` to set the banners, no problem. Now I want to add a sortOrder integer to each of the banners.

Here I am setting the association:

```
Portfolio.belongsToMany(models.Version, { through: models.PortfolioBanner, foreignKey: 'portfolioId', otherKey: 'versionId', as: 'banners' });

Version.belongsToMany(models.Portfolio, { through: models.PortfolioBanner, foreignKey: 'versionId', otherKey: 'portfolioId', as: 'portfolios' });
```

Here is my `PortfolioBanner` model:

```
const PortfolioBanners = sequelize.define('PortfolioBanner', {
    sortOrder: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
    }
});
```

I don't think I can use setBanners, because each of the sortOrder values are different. There is another method call addAssociation which I thought I could use by looping through the banners and setting each one individually.

This was my latest attempt, but it didn't work. I set the banners to null and then individually add each banner. But what seems to happen is that it partially works. Some of the banners are missing after setting them like this.

```
portfolio.setBanners(null);
banners.forEach(banner => {
    portfolio.addBanner(banner.id, {
        sortOrder: banner.sortOrder
    });
});
```

So the question is how can I set the sortOrder of my associated banners?

Here is the link to the sequelize docs I have been referencing.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/

**UPDATE**
Using the loop method above partially works, however say I add banner 1 as an association. Then I want to add banner 2. I set all banners to null and then loop through banner 1 and 2 adding them with `addBanner`, banner 1 will not persist but banner 2 will be there. Now say I add banner 3, banner 2 will be gone, but banner 1 and 3 will persist.

Answer (score 0):

Running `forEach` after `setBanners(null)` seemed to be a race condition. `setBanners` returns a promise. The for loop needs to be ran after `setBanners` resolves.

```
result.setBanners(null).then(() => {
    banners.forEach(banner => {
        result.addBanner(banner.id, {
            sortOrder: banner.sortOrder
        });
    });
    cb(null, result);
});
```